# Why do TypeScript type definitions for some npm libraries (e.g. Facebook SDK) have no exports?

Tags: typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

In the DefinitelyTyped repo, why do some libraries' type definition files have exports while others don't?  For example, the type definition file for the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/facebook-js-sdk/index.d.ts) lacks exports, but the type definition file for the [Amazon Alexa SDK](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/alexa-sdk/index.d.ts) has exports.

I'm asking because the Facebook SDK is the first library I've encountered that lacked exports. I discovered this when I tried to `import {AuthResponse} from 'facebook-js-sdk'` and the compiler complained that `.../node_modules/@types/facebook-js-sdk/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

Is there some benefit to omitting exports from type definitions, thereby requiring that the entire SDK is imported (e.g. `import 'facebook-js-sdk'`) instead of being able to import just a few types?  Or is `@types/facebook-js-sdk` simply not written using the latest TypeScript best practices?

Also, does the "import everything" export-less style of type definitions have any downsides or problems associated with it that I should watch out for in my code that's importing it?

Finally, let's say someone accepted a PR to add exports to the Facebook SDK's typings. Would that be a breaking change for existing clients of that type definition?  (If so that explains why this hasn't been fixed!)

Answer (score 4):

I think author talking about [@types/facebook-js-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/facebook-js-sdk) npm module which provides types for facebook JS SDK.

And it should be imported with

```
import 'facebook-js-sdk';
```

Than you'll be able to use `FB.init(params)` and `params` will be required to have type `InitParams`. So typechecking will work.

Answer (score -1):

Let's have a look how the [Facebook SDK is supposed to be used](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart):

> The Facebook SDK for JavaScript doesn't have any standalone files that
>   need to be downloaded or installed, instead you simply need to include
>   a short piece of regular JavaScript in your HTML that will
>   asynchronously load the SDK into your pages. The async load means that
>   it does not block loading other elements of your page.

After that, you can use SDK by referring to a single global variable, `FB`, defined by that piece of javacsript code.

Note that nowhere in the process you had to `import` anything, Facebook SDK does not use modules.

That's the reason why type declarations for Facebook SDK do not have any exports - that's just not the way the underlying javascript code is supposed to work.

Comment: Typescript needs the types of the functions etc to be defined. That's what's in  @types/facebook-js-sdk.